# DotNet Build insider docker on Azure self hosted windows agent

Tags: .net, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am currently running azure pipelines on self-hosted windows agents and trying to build DotNet inside docker image.

unfortunately it is throwing the following error.

```
  2022-10-07T14:37:49.3562427Z C:\Program 
  Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.401\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning 
  MSB3101: Could not write state file 
  "obj\Release\net6.0\Core.Edge.csproj.AssemblyReference.cache". Access to the path 
  'C:\src\Core.Edge\obj\Release\net6.0\Core.Edge.csproj.AssemblyReference.cache' is 
  denied. [C:\src\Core.Edge\Core.Edge.csproj]
  2022-10-07T14:37:49.4019708Z C:\Program 
  Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.401\Roslyn\Microsoft.Managed.Core.targets(190,5): error MSB4018: 
  The "GenerateMSBuildEditorConfig" task failed unexpectedly. 
  [C:\src\Core.Edge\Core.Edge.csproj]
  2022-10-07T14:37:49.4021276Z C:\Program 
  Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.401\Roslyn\Microsoft.Managed.Core.targets(190,5): error MSB4018: 
  System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path  
 C:\src\Core.Edge\obj\Release\net6.0\CoreEdge.GeneratedMSBuildEditorConfig.editorconfig' 
 is denied. [C:\src\Core.Edge\Core.Edge.csproj]
 2022-10-07T14:37:49.4035181Z C:\Program 
 Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.401\Roslyn\Microsoft.Managed.Core.targets(190,5): error MSB4018:    
 at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost 
 taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket 
 bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [C:\src\Core.Edge\Core.Edge.csproj]
 2022-10-07T14:37:49.4110689Z C:\Program 
 Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.401\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5650,5): error 
 MSB3491: Could not write lines to file 
 "obj\Release\net6.0\Core.Edge.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt". Access to the path 
 'C:\src\Core.Edge\obj\Release\net6.0\Core.Edge.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt' is denied. 
 [C:\src\Core.Edge\Core.Edge.csproj]
 2022-10-07T14:37:49.4170329Z C:\Program  
 Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.401\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5650,5): error 
 MSB3491: Could not write lines to file 
 "obj\Release\net6.0\PDIModule.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt". Access to the path 
 'C:\src\PDIModule\obj\Release\net6.0\PDIModule.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt' is denied. 
  [C:\src\PDIModule\PDIModule.csproj]
```

this build gets failed on both self-hosted and microsoft-hosted windows agent. but it get passed on Microsoft hosted ubuntu agent.

could someone help is it something permission issue on the agent or code level issue ?.